# What's the point of having hidden input in HTML? What are common uses for this?

Tags: html, forms, input

I don't see the benefit of having hidden input? If you set the value of the hidden input why not just use that value at the point where you reference this hidden input?

There are reasons for this but I just don't know them.

Comment: Another point: `hidden` inputs are so easily viewable with DOM inspectors/modern browsers that I'd be in favor of changing the name to something different

Comment: @JLewkovich they do not display/render so they are hidden data. But by no means secret.

Comment: @Mindwin They do render in the server side, and yet visible through the DOM inspector. At least that's what happens when using Razor from .NET

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They're used to pass data that will be needed when the form is submitted. One of the more common cases would be a form allowing users to edit some existing entry. You'll need to know which entry they're editing so that you can update the correct row in the database when they submit the form. The user doesn't need to edit (or even know) the ID of the entry though, so a hidden field works well here.

#### Other options

**URL parameters**:
This could also be done by building the parameters into the url that the form is being submitted to:

```
<form action="save.php?entry_id=1234">
```

but this means you have to handle building the URL properly and escaping the data yourself, and the length of URLs servers will accept is limited so it may not work for longer data.  So generally using hidden form fields is the easier way to go.

**Session variables**: When the edit page loads you'd store the entry ID in a session variable, and then retrieve it on the page that saves the changes. That's a lot easier to mess up though; setting up and maintaining sessions may require adding code in several different places, and then their session could expire in between loading and saving, and you have to make sure it works if they have multiple windows or tabs open, and you have to make sure it doesn't do weird things when they hit back/forward. Because of all these potential pitfalls it isn't a great way to solve this problem--passing the id with the data being submitted is a lot more robust.

**Cookies**: In many languages/frameworks sessions are tracked using cookies, so they're basically the same solution. The pitfalls are the same as for session variables even when sessions are tracked by other methods though.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response! Are there any other alternatives besides building the paramaters into the URL?

Comment: @KRB - I added a couple more ways to accomplish the same thing. They're not necessarily better ways, but they have their uses.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it that way, someone can always tamper it and start messing around. This kind of data should be sent by POST and not GET. Input hidden shouldn't have an connection on databases at all.

Comment: @Namari I can't tell what you're objecting to. Choosing `GET` vs `POST` should be decided based on whether the submission has any side effects (such as updating a record)-- there's no difference between them in terms of security. Data always has to be validated on the server side.

Comment: @Brad, yes I don't know what I wrote that, but let's say GET is much easier to tamper than a POST but that wasn't the question :) Of course you need to check both of them before doing anything with it.

Answer (score 10):

It sends additional information that the user doesn't know or isn't interested in (such as a security token) so that if the form is submitted twice, you can compare the tokens and reject/accept that submission.

Answer (score 3):

Not using hidden inputs means the server needs to keep track of these values instead. This requires the server to keep state, which could otherwise be embedded into the request (form) itself. This may make the page *RESTless* (not RESTful), i.e. break the self-containedness of an HTTP request. If you *did* keep track of hidden values on the server, you would at least need to embed a unique token into each form to deal with several different unique submissions of the same form. The cleanest way to embed such a token is, drumroll, through a hidden input. :)

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate a little more about "drumroll"? Any suggested reading on that?

Answer (score 3):

The Hidden Input field is not displayed on the page, so it does not allow visitors to add anything into it. The Hidden Input allows you, the webmaster, to add specific information to a form, to be passed through the form processor along with the data entered by the visitor.

For example, if you have several forms on different pages on your website, you could use a Hidden tag, in each form, that identifies which page the visitor was on when they filled out the form.

Answer (score 2):

The hidden input is for when you want to send information back on a post without the user seeing the data as a UI element.

The web is stateless - ergo, when a POST comes in, you have only a couple pieces of information to determine what you need to do; Session, Url, some ServerVariables, and the Form data passed to you.

If a piece of data is transient that is not useful for putting in the session, sometimes it is prudent to put into a hidden field.

They can also be useful for storing data on the client side for rich internet applications (such as a product Id that is easily accessible to use in ajax calls).

Answer (score 1):

because you have a php while loop with alot of different objects which you can't get the id's of later and you just save them by storing them in the hidden input... also i like them to be a security check to know my users aren't messing with my post variables through tamper data

Answer (score 1):

If you build a tag system like the one here. You can set the values into a a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a form that's being displayed to edit a record in a database, one technique is to bake the id of that record in a hidden input and have it submitted back so the server can read it back.

It's also used frequently for security purposes (as genesis has said).

Another reason might be for javascript-oriented scenarios, perhaps for non standard controls such as treeviews, where the concept of a selected node cannot be represented as a normal input.  Instead, JS can manipulate a hidden field and store the node's name/id in it, so that it can be read by the server.

Answer (score 1):

It's just what it's name implies, a form input that is hidden from the user.  It's a way of getting data to the server that the user doesn't need to see or control directly.  This is especially useful for maintaining state.

I'm working on a project right now where a user creates several items that are represented as data objects in JavaScript and serialized when sent to the server.  These data items are expressed one way when displayed to the user with HTML, another way as JavaScript, and a third way when sent to the server.  A hidden input is the *only* way to accomplish this.  (Okay, fine not actually the only way, but certainly the most reasonable way).

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you have a form to edit an entity from you data model, you could use an hidden input to place the id of the entity you are updating, since you don't want to have this value put in the text input field to be posted back to the server.  the hidden field will be posted to the server as if it were part of your form.

Answer (score 1):

All answers explained why we using hidden inputs in form but here is the security concern.

**Security concern**

Using hidden inputs in forms can be tampered/changed by View source or using developer tools in any browser.

**Solution**

> Use cryptography in your code/project to avoid changing values in
>   hidden input by attackers/hackers.

**Generic Solution**

If you want to store any data in hidden input first encrypt the data and store them in hidden input. 
When form is submitted then decrypt them if values not change then save your data.
If changed then show some error or else.

**Further reading**

[Cryptography](https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/cryptography)

[Wiki Cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography)

---

**For framework Developers**

Other framework developers can find cryptography in their framework.

[Cryptography in Laravel(PHP)](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/encryption)

[Cryptography in .Net](https://www.meziantou.net/cryptography-in-dotnet.htm)

[Cryptography in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/signing/)

Answer (score 0):

As name implies, Hidden fields are similar to other input fields except one difference i.e, hidden fields are not actually shown to the user and hence can not be edited by the user.Its value can only be set at the time of execution i.e. may be form submitting which posts the data to the server.
But the data set on the html page i.e. name/value can be seen in the html source of the page (view source of the page).