# How to make the hidden element visible using java script executor

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, selenium

Currently am working on Selenium Webdriver with Java

Am trying to click on a button but i can't able to click because it is hidden. Please let me know how to make the hidden element visible 1st then how can click the button.

Please give me some example and my HTML tag is:

```
<input id="iskpiFilterAction" type="hidden" value="1" name="isKpiFilterAction">
```

Comment: it is an hidden input element... why do you want to click it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, your question doesn't make sense for me. But I can exactly answer for your question.

For selenium 2 (webdriver):

```
WebDriver driver = ...

JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jsExecutor.executeScript("document.getElementById('iskpiFilterAction').type = 'button';");
```

Result is:

[image: button]

This code causes changing type of element (from hidden to button), but it doesn't make sense for all of us. These two elements have different purpose/use. For more information see:

- [Original purpose of <input type="hidden">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293741/original-purpose-of-input-type-hidden)
- [What's the point of having hidden input in HTML? What are common uses for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324950/whats-the-point-of-having-hidden-input-in-html-what-are-common-uses-for-this)
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp

Answer (score 0):

I didnt quiet understand the question.. However .. if you have a hidden object which you want to unhide dynamically using JavaScript using some trigger, this is a way you could do that:

```
<head>
<script>
function unhide()
{
    document.getElementById("iskpiFilterAction").type = "button";
} 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="unhide()">
<input id="iskpiFilterAction" type="hidden" value="1" name="isKpiFilterAction">
</body>
```

I am using body onload event to unhide the object so the moment this page loads you will see the button which u can then click. However if you want it some be triggered at some other event you can use the function accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mentioned that am using Java to implement code.

Comment: @Arun P Johny The thing is am targeting the ID to click the button. The problem is the ID is hidden so am searching solution for that scenario

Comment: I dont think its doable with java ... Your best bet with java would be to open [http connection](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) with the page's URL using java and send form's expected parameter to emulate button click behavior on a typical browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("iskpiFilterAction"));  
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.type = 'button';", element);
```