# Adding variable to ajax post in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got post ajax request in vanilla javascript, all works well, but I need to add an variable to `form_data`, which will be send to php. 
For example variable `apple = 1` is already in form_data. I need to add `orange = 2`, but I can't do it in my html form. My js code is below:

```
function button_publish_ajax(variable){
    var form = document.getElementById("form-buttons");
    var form_data = new FormData(form);
        for ([key,value] of form_data.entries()){
        console.log(key + ': '+value);
        }
    var action = form.getAttribute("action");                   
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', action, true);
    xhr.overrideMimeType('text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        var result = xhr.responseText;
        console.log("Result:" + result);
    }
    };
    xhr.send(form_data);
   }
```

To sum up: I want to add `orange=1` to form_data. Anyone knows how to do it?
My primary intention was to add information which button was clicked to differentiate ajax functions in php. My HTML code is below:

```
 <form method="post" action="cms_offers_button.php" id="form-buttons">
  <input type="hidden" name="offer_list" value="12">
    <input name="PublishListItem" type="button" class="btn btn-info offer-publish" value="Publish" id="publish-12" style="display: none;"/>
    <input name="WithdrawListItem" type="button" class="btn btn-info offer-withdraw" value="Withdraw" id="withdraw-12"/>
    <input name="EditListItem" type="button" class="btn btn-default offer-edit" value="Edit" id="edit-12" />
    <input name="DeleteListItem" type="button" class="btn btn-danger offer-delete" value="Delete" id="delete-12"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it using **[`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)** function like:

```
//form_data.append(name, value);

form_data.append('orange',2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is appending form data, better practice than using hidden input fields? they seem to both do the exact same thing. Hidden Input Fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324950/whats-the-point-of-having-hidden-input-in-html-what-are-common-uses-for-this

Comment: That depend on the case.. If the value will be statically added or passed from server side

Comment: I used hidden input fields, but I cannot use them in this case. I've got a form, which has 3 buttons: "publish", "delete", "show", and I need to differentiate ajax action for each one in js functions

Comment: Add the HTML code to the question please and try to describe more which values you want to pass ..